# Accessing website via domain and IP address redirects different places

Tags: dns, hostname

I have successfully configured my website on this IP: http://165.227.99.227

Also, I have this domain http://omerselcuk.engineer which I have configured DNS records. I have checked that with several IP address from hostname online services (e.g. [ipinfo.info](https://ipinfo.info/html/ip_checker.php)). The domain name points to my IP.

The problem is, while I can successfully view my website via IP address, when I try to access it via hostname it shows default nginx welcome page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just forget to change `server_name` in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/[projectname]` from IP to real domain name. That resolved the issue.